Redirect broadcast udp packets to another interface
This is my first question. I am so sorry if that is a simple one.
I am trying to redirect broadcast packets to wlan0:xxxx to another device, which is connected to the current device via USB cables(usb0).
I am working on extracting some data from an Android device, and the data is udp broadcast packets to 255.255.255.255:xxxx, and this packet is readable from wlan0:xxxx. I try to use tcpdump -i wlan0 and it seems the packets can be captured. wlan0 is actually used for obtaining data so it is set to monitor mode, I cannot get IP address of wlan0 from ifconfig. I know this is weird, but the data-collection firmware is designed to take wlan0 and return data by broadcasting it to xxxx port of wlan0. That is why I can use tcpdump to save them.
However, I wish to send these udp packets to another interface which is usb0, since I connect my Android device with a raspberry Pi and I hope to receive data from the Pi-side sockets. I tried to use DNAT but broadcast packets targeting 255.255.255.255 cannot be handled. Then I think I can simply use socat to redirect the packets received from wlan0:xxxx to a new target. At this time, I find I am confused about interfaces and ports.
wlan0 is in monitor mode and I am not sure if it is possible to pass data from wlan0, also, I have the IP address of this Android device as well as my raspberry Pi, but the name of the interface seems to be different. If I need to redirect these packets, should I send them to the interface of the Android or directly send it to the IP address of raspberry Pi? Will they go though?
Another thing is that, before using the Android device, I tried to capture data from my raspberry Pi, which also has a wlan0 and can be set to monitor mode. I used DatagramSocket to read data from wlan0:xxxx, but since I need to connect to the internet to pass the data, I plugged a wi-fi adapter to the raspberry Pi and use that adapter for connection. I thus feel curious that when I use DatagramSocket, why it was bind to wlan0:xxxx instead of adapter:xxxx(a new interface).
Thank you very much!

Some update. I use tcpdump -w - option to output data directly and use socat to create a new udp packet, then send it to my raspi. It works, but I want only one udp packet for each packet I captured in tcpdump. It seems socat will collect many packets until the buffer is full.. What should I do?
